# Insertion of brackets and quotation marks using Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have recently started writing some scripts for Google Spreadsheets. I have no experience with Javascript though and I have question that is concerning a (as I suppose) basic issue.

I would like my script to insert data shown below into a cell in a sheet. How should I encode it to make it work?

```
komorkaLinku.setValue("=HYPERLINK("http://www.some.link/some/data"+variable+"something","something")");
```

I had tried several ways but none of them worked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are trying to include quotes inside quoted text. There are a couple of ways to do that.

1. Use single quotes inside double quotes, or vice-versa.

   ```
   komorkaLinku.setValue('=HYPERLINK("http://www.some.link/some/data'+variable+'"something","something")');
   ```
2. Use escaped single quotes.

   ```
   komorkaLinku.setValue('=HYPERLINK(\'http://www.some.link/some/data'+variable+'\'something\',\'something\')');
   ```

As @ScampMichael comments, it would be a better choice to use `setFormula()` in this case. You would still need to handle embedded quotes properly.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I had tried using the escaped single quotes and single quotes between single ones before posting the question but the issue that stopped my script (and I thought it was the above quote problem) was at other place in the code. I could not detect it because the script is executing on form submit and the error logs were sent to me just today :) Thank you anyways!

Comment: Rather than wait for the notification, you can often see what happened with the last trigger by using "View - Execution Transcript..." in the editor.

Comment: Oh, thank you again. That will save me a lot of time and nerves. Regards!

Comment: Probably better to use .setFormula()